# PHP: @! vs !@ -- whats the diff?

Tags: php

I am working on `file_get_contents` func (I know notices on network issue's and Returns `FALSE` indicating operation failure). For now I don't care about the network errors and I just i want the network res and keep trying until i get it.

So, i put `@` before the the func to stop notices from making my cli window full of unwanted texts.

And To make the thing work in a loop i added `!`

```php
while (($data=!@file_get_contents('http://example.com/')) === false);
```

But What diff does it make from this,

```php
while (($data=@!file_get_contents('http://example.com/')) === false);
```

> So, My question is whats the difference between them??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@!file_get_contents` = The `!` evaluates the result of the function as a boolean (`true` or `false`). The `@` suppresses all warnings from the result of the expression.

`!@file_get_contents` = The  `@` suppresses all warnings from the function, then the `!` evaluates the result of the error-suppressed function as a boolean (`true` or `false`).

**Edit**: My answer was marked as accepted, so I edited with the correct behavior from `iainn`'s answer.

Comment: Interesting, but as of https://3v4l.org/dPINA from `iainn`s answer, there seemed to be no diff??

Comment: @MDAl-AMIN  Yeah, iainn is right on that. I didn't knew. My thinking is to not suppress what does not need to be suppressed, because otherwise how do you know if there is an issue with the function or somewhere in the expression

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer: they're functionally identical

`@` is the [PHP error suppression operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), which results in hiding all errors from the subsequent expression.

When you say

```
!@function()
```

, you're saying to suppress all errors that might arise from `function()` (and any deeper function calls, etc), and then negating the result.

With

```
@!function()
```

the whole of `!function()` is treated as the expression, and so any errors from the function are again hidden.

See https://3v4l.org/dPINA for an example - notice how the warning is suppressed in both cases.